# angular directive that conditionally creates content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive such that an element with attribute `if-login-service="facebook"` will be created, but an element with any other value for this attribute will not.

The progress I've made with this directive so far is shown below

```
app.directive('ifLoginService', function($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    compile: function compile(element, attrs) {

      return function($scope, $element, $attr) {

        var serviceName = attrs.ifLoginService;

        if (serviceName === 'facebook') {

          // use compile to include and compile your content here
          $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

[**A Plunker demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AWTPi5?p=preview) is available here. If it were working, the "Facebook" button would be displayed and the "Not Facebook" button would not. Currently both buttons are displayed, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You can look at the [source of ngIf](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js), or you can just use ng-if in your directive template

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky could you show how I could use `ng-if` in my directive template?

Comment: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/yoavmatchulsky/aed5d49ca26c2f747ccc5632222941fe). keep in mind that the button element will still exists. that's not ideal and that's why I didn't wrote this as an answer.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky thanks, but obviously I'd prefer if this behaved like `ng-if`, i.e. the elements are not created if the condition is false

Comment: so you'll have to implement interaction between the directive and the page. Unless your directive is always on a <button> element, and then you can just create a tag directive and use a button in the button

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky No, the directive could be on any type of element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use compile service to write your directive.

```
$compile('your html content here')($scope);
```

To clear root element such as button use this:

```
$element[0].html('');
```

Or remove it from DOM:

```
$element[0].parentNode.removeChild($element[0]);
```

Here is your directive repaired:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    toggle: 'true'
  };
});

app.directive('ifLoginService', function($compile,$animate) {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    compile: function compile(element, attrs) {

      return function($scope, $element, $attr) {

        var serviceName = attrs.ifLoginService;
        console.debug('Testing service name', serviceName);

        if (serviceName === 'true') {
          // use compile to include and compile your content here
          $element.html($compile($element.contents())($scope));
        }
        else
        {
          $element[0].parentNode.removeChild($element[0]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Link to plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uzfAsEniM9dbeX1DwVWN?p=preview)

Comment: I've made a Plunker demo based on your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work https://plnkr.co/edit/AWTPi5?p=preview

Comment: I updated your plunkr, see link above. Html also changed to hide/show directive based on model.toggle